# Extracting PDF content using the Adobe API

Tags: java, pdf, adobe

I am trying to read the content of a PDF file which consists of a number of tables. Using Java with the Adobe API, I am able to extract the content in table if all the cells have a signle line of content. The problem comes when a cell has multiple lines, causing the extracted content to move to the next line hence causing misalignment with the table headers.

Is there any way I can extract the content as is from the PDF, keeping the table format the same way as it displays in the PDF? I'm currently using the \t escape character to extract the data.

Comment: Usually the extraction of raw data from a print format requires the application to locate anchor points to know when to transition state.  In your table, you may have anchor points in the form of dividing lines or some kind of key text.  I don't miss doing this kind of work.

Answer (score 1):

An old question - but now one with a new answer.  Adobe are set to release a brand new [PDF Extract API](https://opensource.adobe.com/pdftools-sdk-docs/beta/extract/#java) (currently in [private beta](https://www.adobe.io/apis/documentcloud/dcsdk/extractbetaform.html) but with a prospective launch date of June 2021), which is designed to solve this problem and many others.  I'm not a cheerleader for Adobe, so I won't wax lyrical about it here; but we are very satisfied customers.

Answer (score 0):

Text in a PDF is not formatted. They just appear to be formatted. Similarly, tables are just line drawings and text amidst them. You need a PDF library that can intelligently reconstruct the page elements. But no matter how smart the library there will always be a few lines that are broken.

Here is a screenshot of an attempt by PDFOne, a Java PDF library made by my company. To be fair, there may other libraries that can do the same. You will have to do some testing with your collection of PDFs to see which one is good.

http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=232&t=PDF_Text_Search_And_PDF_Text_Extraction_Using_PDFOne_for_Java

[image]